# Trying to test some code in Pharo 2.0 and it depends on BlockContext which was dropped?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Trying to test some code in Pharo 2.0 and it depends on BlockContext which was dropped, what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide some more information such as incriminating code, debug errors, etc, and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to load Magritte2 in something newer than Pharo 1.3 with - 

Gofer it
squeaksource: 'MetacelloRepository';
package: 'ConfigurationOfMagritte2';
load.
(ConfigurationOfMagritte2 project version: '2.0.6') load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Pharo 4 and run Magritte 3 and Seaside 3.1, as that are the stable versions. The major change in Magritte 3, introduced and [explained](http://forum.world.st/Magritte-3-td4401357.html) early 2012, is the moving of the descriptions to the instance side, and renaming description to magritteDescription. You can find sample code of Seaside & Magritte in a QCMagritte image you can download from [CI](http://ci.inria,fr/pharo-contribution/QCMagritte), in addition to the [plain magritte builds](http://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/Magritte3)

Otherwise, just check the pharo, seaside and pier mailing lists of 4 years ago and the monticello repositories to see what changed. There have been lots of little changes because of the improvements in Squeak and Pharo in the past 4 years.

If you need to use Magritte 2 to migrate legacy code you might want to take a look (with Pharo 5) at my experimental MonticelloProjects code on Smalltalkhub. That builds a data structure of all source code in the Monticello packages in a project repository, allowing you to more easily see what changed when.